# Get date from description string in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I would like to know if there is a way to find and convert a date from a string which contain some other informations like :

*"Your driver will be here on Monday"* or *"Be present the November 24th"* for example.

In order to create a NSDate from this information.

Thank you guys !

Comment: "Your driver will be here on Monday". How one can analyze that Monday is on 14 november 2016 it may be on 13 nov 2015. it's not possible. and for the second one "Be present the November 24th" it's possible but you need to write some information. it depend upon your string

Comment: Its very difficult to find the date from a dynamic text.

Comment: Have you tried `NSDataDetector` (https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsdatadetector?language=objc)?

Comment: Were you able to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Please try below function:

```
-(void)fetchDateFromString:(NSString*)stringObj
{

    NSError *error = NULL;
    NSDataDetector *detectorObj = [NSDataDetector dataDetectorWithTypes:(NSTextCheckingTypes)NSTextCheckingTypeDate error:&error];

    NSArray *matchesObj = [detectorObj matchesInString:stringObj
                                         options:0
                                           range:NSMakeRange(0, [stringObj length])];

    NSLocale* currentLoc = [NSLocale currentLocale];
    for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matchesObj) {
        if ([match resultType] == NSTextCheckingTypeDate) {
            NSLog(@"Date : %@", [[match date] descriptionWithLocale:currentLoc]);
        }
    }
}
```

And invoke as below:

```
[self fetchDateFromString:@"Be present the November 24th"];
```

Good Luck.....